# Kusto time chart change legend name

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto time chart that has Legend from the Query. I would like to remove the additional text from this Legend which is visible in the chart. Could you please tell me how I do it in KQL?

for example, from below I would like to remove the word ValueName and Value from the Legend and display just the Win_T3.

ValueName: Win_T3 : Value -> Win_T3

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Neha

Comment: The `adx` tag is for Intel's arbitrary-precision arithmetic instruction set for the x86 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Well... not exactly, but you can do some trick by using `\0` based aliases (`['\0']`, `['\0\0']` etc.)

```
// Generate data sample. Not part of the solution
let t = materialize (range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend dt  = ago(7d*rand()), ValueName = strcat('Win_T', tostring(toint(rand()*5))));
// Solution Starts here
t
| make-series ['\0'] = count() on dt step 1d by ['\0\0'] = ValueName
| render timechart
```

[image: Legend]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAz2Ou07DQBBFe0v%20h9t5HSXYKRBFRJ0uTRAUgNDgndgr9mHtjiVA%20XgGEjHdPM6d03XYc%20RMwrAkhEJh9nyDQxLMlAXpBJkYJflFXIp15VkguEdQJjvy7pthMsWR4XDKKWALSdj2fY8iPGt7Bn8KRwsrUJLGZO7sShlr2naNR/ILHyiw7orkgcQ0Ty6%20PTRrTdKJi6OR5KKYC7O6bbV2ddV1OF7FcBTVLZg4c11JXZ3V8IM3RSW54Ll56ZtXfTCkRXNaKKE2F0GL96%20/i%20vNv9BvSlZxzhAXeJj0xQ/AesKnMwEAAA==)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'd love to know more about why this works.